# Executing long rsync subprocess from Python asynchronously

Tags: apache, python-2.7, flask, subprocess, rsync

I am writing a simple web-based utility using Python 2.7, Flask and Apache, which copies large folders from one place to another. The code does a non-blocking subprocess call to rsync, which logs its output to a file:

```
with open(log_file, "wb") as out:
    subprocess.Popen(['rsync', '-vha', '--info=progress2', source, target], stdout=out, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

So the user sends a request and is able to see the progress. The problem is that when the directory if very large (more than 100 Gb), rsync terminates before it finishes all work.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Does subprocess call have some timeout, after which it is terminated? Is it a feature of Python, Flask, or Apache?
2. Is simple subprocess call a suitable solution in this case? Should I consider using something more advanced?

Comment: you should use a task queue like celery to do long running tasks

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply, I'll try it!